# Save value on array by useing edit component

Tags: delphi

Hello can u help me solve this please. I would search by myself, but i dont have lots of time so im asking you.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
my_array_item:array[0..100] of string;
begin
    my_array_item[0]:=edit1.Text;

end;
```

I got error if i try to assign edit1.text value to array item.

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(556): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Dynamic array' and 'string'
```

how can i solve this error? thank you

Comment: You're so short of time that you felt compelled to post fake code that does not match the error message? Please try harder.

Comment: i edited my long code because i thought it would be complicated to understand my porblem if code is long...

Comment: Posting fake code that doesn't relate to your error message is no use though is it? You need to stop rushing and take your time to loop at the problem properly. Work out exactly what the problem is and cut the code down to the simplest reproduction that you can. Of course the error message explains the problem. You are assigning a string to a dynamic array. And obviously you cannot do that.

Comment: If you expect us to spend time to figure out your problem, then you should also spend the time to give us a reproduction of your issue.

Comment: @RolandsSosnars : If you're developing software, and you want to delegate your 5 minutes of time to fix a simple compiler error because you don't have time for it yourself, then i'd say : don't bother, your development project is doomed.  Why should we spend our precious time on a lost case when you don't even want to describe your problem properly?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the code in the question bears no relation to the error. Since you've obviously pasted that error message, the real code must indeed produce the error. Let's look at the error:

```
[dcc32 Error]: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Dynamic array' and 'string'
```

You see error E2010 when you attempt an assignment of two things that are not assignment compatible. In this case you are attempting to assign a string to a dynamic array, something that is a syntax error.

Your code therefore looks like this:

```
var
  arr: array of SomeType;
  s: string;
....
arr := s;
```